# convert json data to react components with ajax requests

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs

I have a problem in convertion json data to react components with ajax requests.
My json file is under "src/data/form-inputs.json".

The content of **form-inputs.json** is

```
{
  "form_inputs": [
    {
        "label": "Sender Email",
        "name": "sender_mail",
        "type": "email",
        "value": null,
        "rules": "required|min:3|max:64",
        "options": [],
        "default_value": null,
        "multiple": false,
        "readonly": false,
        "placeholder": "Sender Email",
        "info": "Example value of how to fill the input"
    }
  ]
```

}

Under "src/components/form.js" is **form.js** file that converts json data to **React.js** components. The code of form.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            form_inputs: []
        };
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('../test-json/form-inputs.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                  isLoaded: true,
                  form_inputs: result.form_inputs
             });
        });
}

render() {
    const {isLoaded, form_inputs} = this.state;
    if(!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }else{
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {form_inputs.map(form_input => (
                        <li>
                            {form_input.label}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
  }
```

}

```
export default Form
```

Please can somebody help me with this problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: 1. What exactly is the error you are getting. 2. Why do you need to fetch the json file. Just import it `import formInputs from '../test-json/form-inputs.json'` then parse it: `form_inputs = JSON.parse(formInputs);`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal the error that I get is "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: @VaibhavVishal can you build the code please?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your json file. No need it parse it, javascript interpreter will automatically parse it for you. You don't need a state anymore in your component. Just loop in the imported json.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import formData from "./formData.json";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {formData.form_inputs.map(form_input => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <label for={form_input.label}>{form_input.label}</label>
            <input
              key={form_input.label}
              id={form_input.label}
              type={form_input.type}
              name={form_input.name}
              defaultValue={form_input.default_value}
              placeholder={form_input.placeholder}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/94o4zkkl3r?fontsize=14) to see it in action.